# NetBeans PHP does not break on exception

Tags: windows, exception, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I'm trying to debug some PHP using **NetBeans PHP 6.8 with XAMPP** on Windows and setup **xdebug** in **php.ini**. The step by step seem working fine but when there is a critical exception on the website in the PHP, NetBeans doesn't break on it.

I heard about adding a break-point on Exception but I couldn't find it in NetBeans 6.8. The Ctrl + Shift + F8 doesn't let me break on "Exception", only "Method".

Comment: I tried changing remote_mode to "jit" in php.ini and in the code with no result, except it doesn't break on the first line when starting debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like your comment says, you generally need to have the remote_mode set to 'jit'.

If debugging isn't working, there are a few things you can check:

- Add a `xdebug_break();` line in your code, and see if the debugger fires.
- Add some logging into your php.ini/xdebug.ini file:

  ```
  xdebug.remote_log="C:\temp\xdebug.log"
  ```

  Look at that log file to see if you are getting breakpoint events mentioned.
- Check phpinfo() to see you have output like this:

```
        This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
        Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
            with Xdebug v2.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2008, by Derick Rethans
```

If you don't have the "with Xdebug" line, even if you have a complete set of xdebug options listed, you will get output, xdebug_break() debugging, but no user-set breakpoints.  This could also be your problem with exception breakpoints.

The general cause for this is loading the xdebug extensions the wrong way.  You need to load it as `zend_extension=/path/to/xdebug.so` - remove any other lines loading it starting with "extension=" or "zend_extension_ts=".

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using xDebug it might be a good idea to [activate the profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#profiler_enable)

On windows you can use [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) to read the file.